# Identifier 'isCollapsed' is not defined

Tags: angular

I'm following a tutorial but I don't know why this doesn't work.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AppComponent {
 isCollapsed: boolean = true;
}
```

From another component, I have this tag with error on `isCollapsed` property:

```
<div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent" [collapse]="isCollapsed">
```

This tag is part of this component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-superior',
  templateUrl: './menu-superior.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-superior.component.css']
})
export class MenuSuperiorComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

If I declare `isCollapsed` inside `MenuSuperiorComponent`, the problem is solved. Is it possible declare a property on `app-root` to be used in another component?

[image]

Comment: `isCollapsed` is defined in another class. It is not visible from another component unless you pass that value to it.

Comment: No, you should declare it in all components that use it. You can pass the value along in your templates if you want. Alternatively you could use inheritance but for a simple boolean field I would just declare where necessary.

Comment: `I'm following a tutorial but I don't know why this doesn't work.` <= it might also help if you pasted the link to the tutorial. If you just want to learn angular then I can also highly recommend the [angular tour of heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial)

Comment: @Igor It is a purchased tutorial. There is no way to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need communication between components use a service with an observable.  Setup like so:

**collapsed.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CollapsedService {
  collapsedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  // It's important to use BehaviorSubject and not just Subject, because
  // BehaviorSubject will emit the last value when you .subscribe() or "| async".  So if
  // a component subscribes after the value is set then it will still be up to date.
  collapsed: Observable<string> = this.collapsedSubject.asObservable();

   setCollapsed(value: boolean) {
     this.collapsedSubject.next(value);
  }
}
```

**menu-superior.component.ts**

```
export class MenuSuperiorComponent implements OnInit {
  isCollapsed: Observable<boolean>;

  // Inject our new service wherever we need to read or set the collapsed flag.
  constructor(private collapsedService: CollapsedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.isCollapsed = this.collapsedService.collapsed;
  }

}
```

**menu-superior.component.html**

```
<div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent" [collapse]="isCollapsed | async">
```

Anytime you need to set the value just call `this.collapsedService.setCollapse(true/false)` from anywhere in your application.

Be sure to register your new service in the providers array on App.module (or Core.module).

**Further Reading:**
A good article on BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject and AsyncSubject -> 
https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0

Edit:

If you want access to the collapsed variable within a component just subscribe to it using `this.collapsedService.collapsed.subscribe(value => {});`

Answer (score 1):

No you need to have the variable defined in the component if you want that to be used in the component.

In your case isCollapsed is defined in a separate class. Inorder to use it you either need to pass the value to the component or use a shared Service to communicate accross the components.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is declared in component "AppComponent" while being used in MenuSuperiorComponent, hence the error.

The correct set up for these 2 components and the use of this parameter would be as the following:

AppComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

MenuSuperiorComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-superior',
  templateUrl: './menu-superior.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-superior.component.css']
})
export class MenuSuperiorComponent implements OnInit {

  isCollapsed: boolean = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

** Note that the parameter has been moved to **MenuSuperiorComponent**.
This way, parameter is recognized.